# 3D cursor not moving

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, 3d-cursor, object-mode

I don't know quite what happened. I was modeling and I suppose accidentally clicked on something, and now the 3D cursor (The thing in the middle with the red ring around it) stays in the middle.

I've seen ways to snap it to objects, but it'll only snap to that object. If i click on another object it won't automatically go on it. I want the 3D cursor to automatically snap to what object I click. I've tried opening new files but it still won't work.
Anybody know how to make it so it automatically snaps to the middle of the selected object?

Comment: This looks like a combination feature request and bug report. The 3-D cursor is supposed to move where you click, not move to what you select. At least, that’s the way it is with the original keymap with right click being select.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you set a shortcut to your cursor to selected action ?

[image]